# Applying Security Updates to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I currently have a SQL Server that is build level:

- 10.50.4000    2009.100.4000.0 SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 (SP2)

I'm wanting to bring it up to 10.50.4042.

Do I need to run both of the below security updates or just MS15-058 (2009.100.4042)?

- 10.50.4042    2009.100.4042.0 3045313 MS15-058: MS15-058: Description of the security update for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 GDR:
- 10.50.4033    2009.100.4033.0 2977320 MS14-044: Description of the security update for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 (GDR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at [MS15-058](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms15-058.aspx), it says under Update FAQ:

> Second, in the table below, locate your version number or the version range that your version number falls within. The corresponding update is the one you need to install.

In your case this is:

- Update number : `3045313`
- Title : MS15-058: `Description of the security update for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 GDR: July 14, 2015`
- Apply if current product version is… : `10.50.4000.0 or 10.50.4033.0`
- This security update also includes servicing releases up through… : `2008 R2 SP2 GDR (MS14-044)`

This means that you only need to install `Microsoft Security Bulletin MS15-058` to reach 10.50.4042 2009.100.4042